# apache RewriteRule requires trailing slash at the end of url to work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok so i have a url like

```
domain.com/item/item_id/item_description/page
```

when i type the link without

```
/page
```

on the url it throws a 404 error and i have to type the trailing slash on the url to make it work..

this is my htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ item.php?action=item&id=$1&desc=$2&page=$3
```

i have found this after searching:

```
# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

which kinda solves my problem but how can i make the trailing slash to be optional by the user if the user wants to add it or not so it wont redirect everytime a slash is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the request using one rewriterule.

```
RewriteRule ^item(?:\.php)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?$ item.php?action=item&id=$1&desc=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Please note I have added `(?:\.php)` before `^item`, just to be sure this rewriterule works, if your webserver for some reason convert request

```
 domain.com/item/...
```

into

```
 domain.com/item.php/...
```

Tip: you can see your current rewriterule behavior enabling RewriteLog:

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-rewrite_log"
```

Be careful do not use this in production.

Answer (score 0):

Use two rewrite rules (one with and one without "page"):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ item.php?action=item&id=$1&desc=$2
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ item.php?action=item&id=$1&desc=$2&page=$3
```